# Where does SDKMAN install packages?

Tags: package, package-managers, sdkman

I used [SDKMAN!](http://sdkman.io/) to install [Groovy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Groovy) which went fine.

Where is the installed package now? I need the path for it.  I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it should be in one of the dot folders in your home directory.

Comment: this is the installation directory of sdkman, no sign of the installed groovy or grails

Comment: Run `which groovy` to discover the location of the executable.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

I've checked it on my system. It should be located in `$HOME/.sdkman/candidates/`.

Comment: For example, on my Mac I found the installed Java Virtual Machines here:  `/Users/my_user_name_here/.sdkman/candidates/java`

Answer (score 22):

I think the best way would be to use SDKMan's `home` command:

https://sdkman.io/usage#home

Something like this (taken from the above page):

```
$ sdk home java 11.0.7.hs-adpt
/home/somedude/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.7.hs-adpt
```

Comment: "Somedude where's my Java" - starring Ashton Kutcher, Sean William Scott

Answer (score 10):

Upon installation, SDKMAN creates an environment variable `$SDKMAN_DIR` which points to the installation directory.

Usuall it's `~/.sdkman`

Answer (score 2):

After you have run `source $HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh`.
You can see the sdkman "installation" by running:

```
declare -f
```

$HOME on mac is /Users/`<users>`

Answer (score 2):

SDKMAN stores file in `$HOME/.sdkman/candidates/` as Tom mentioned and this answer goes into more detail.

To find where SBT 1.3.13 is installed, type `sdk home sbt 1.3.13`.  It'll return something like `/Users/powers/.sdkman/candidates/sbt/1.3.13`.

The arguments to the `sdk install` command align with where the files are stored in `$HOME/.sdkman/candidates`.

- `sdk install java 8.0.272.hs-adpt` stores files in `$HOME/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.272.hs-adpt`.
- `sdk install sbt 1.3.13` stores files in `$HOME/.sdkman/candidates/sbt/1.3.13`.

When you run `sdk install`, the downloaded binaries get saved in `$HOME/.sdkman/archives`.  For example, `$HOME/.sdkman/archives/java-8.0.272.hs-adpt.zip` and `$HOME/.sdkman/archives/sbt-1.3.13.zip`.

Some of the binaries are pretty big and can end up taking a lot of space on your computer.  You should periodically delete them with the `sdk flush archives` command.  Once you install the software, you don't need the binaries anymore.  See [here](https://mungingdata.com/java/sdkman-multiple-versions-java-sbt-scala/) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Where's SDKMan installed:

```
echo @SDKMAN_DIR
```

Where did it just install gradle? (or some other package)

```
which gradle
```